# Include Project Into Wix Bundle Bootstrapper

Tags: c#, wix, installation, bundle

How can i include my program installer in the bootstrapper? i have this which installs the prerequisites only. i cant get to include my program as an installation msi file or w.e else it can be.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
<Bundle UpgradeCode="fec4e00c-2691-4dfd-ade8-1a83d7d37d36" Version="1.0.0.0">
  <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>
  <Chain>
    <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full"/>
    <PackageGroupRef Id="SQLPackage"/>
  </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to create the msi first. [Here is an example](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/add_a_file.html). If using Visual Studio, you can create a new `Setup Project` to get started.
2. Add the msi from the previous step using an `<MsiPackage>` element. You can insert it right after the prerequisites.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked. um can u link me to a custom action tutorial? i need to execute an exe file at uninstallation and wait for it until it closes. something like using showdialog

Comment: Sure. This one looks good: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx. There are many others online as well.